# Prevent cloudStorageURI From URL Encoding Filename

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-storage

I am using a Firebase function to store an image in Google Cloud Storage.

```js
const bucket = getStorage().bucket()
const [file] = await bucket.upload(localPath, {
  destination: `teams/${teamId}/${fileName}`
})
```

Some object keys might contain a `?` character. E.g. `teams/1234/hello.png?v=1998`

I then store a reference to this uploaded object by using

```
file.cloudStorageURI.href
```

The problem is, the above object key will be stored in my database as

```
teams/1234/hello.png%3Fv=1998
```

Later, when I try to retrieve my object on the frontend, it complains the object is not found.

```
const url = await getDownloadURL(storageRef(storage, datum.storagePath))
```

Is there a way I can get a `gs://` object reference that does not url-encode the filename?

Comment: To ensure compatibility across Cloud Storage tools, you should encode the characters when they appear in either the object name or query string of a request URI.Refer to this [document](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/request-endpoints#encoding) & this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66425640/18265638)